# Integration of a function of 2 arguments where 1 argument is a random vector

Tags: r

I have a function `func` (in R) of 2 variables defined like this (just an example):

```
func <- function(t,gam){return(exp(-t/2)*(t+1)^gam)}
```

The second argument `gam` will be estimated from 2 different sample so basically `gam` is a vector of length 2. What I want to receive is the integration of this function for t: 0->Inf when `gam` is known.

I tried few ways but could not get a vector of values from integration. Any advice will be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `sapply` to deliver the two item vector (separately) to `integrate`:

```
sapply( gam, function(x) integrate( func, lower=0,upper=Inf,  gam=x)$value )
```

Example:

```
> sapply( c(.5,1), function(x) integrate( func, lower=0,upper=Inf,  gam=x)$value )
[1] 3.311359 6.000000
```

Comment: Hi 42-, may I ask a further question here or I should create a new one?

Comment: A simple elaboration of the theme of integration. ask here. Something else; new question.

Comment: I have just posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346802/vector-of-functions-with-2-or-more-random-arguments. Thank you very much.