# Vector of functions with 2 or more random arguments

Tags: r

I have these 4 functions of 2 variables:

```
inner.a0b0<- function(tvar,gamma){
  return(gamma^(1/2)*(1+tvar)^(-(gamma+1)/2)*exp(-tvar/2))} 

K0.inte.func <- function(tvar,gam){return((1-tvar)*(exp(-tvar)-gam^(-1/2)*(1+tvar)^(-(gam+1)/2)*exp(-tvar/2)))}  


unit.l.func <- function(tvar,gam){return((1+tvar)^((gam+1)/2)*exp(-tvar/2))}

beta.G <- function(tvar,gam){(1+tvar)^((gam+1)/2)*exp(-tvar/2)*(1-tvar))}
```

I have 2 different samples from which I get the estimated lambda.es = c(lambda.es.1, lambda.es.2).

Then I have 2 vectors of 2 components by integrating as follows:

```
K0.deno <- sapply(lambda.es, function(x) integrate(inner.a0b0,lower=0,upper=Inf,gam=x)$value)

K0.inte.val<- sapply(lambda.es, function(x) integrate(K0.inte.func,lower=0,upper=Inf,gam=x)$value)
```

My aim now is: First, I define 2 functions (each corresponding to a component of lambda.es) from unit.l.func and beta.G and vectors K0.deno and K0.inte.val, so I write this:

```
K0.operator.b <- function(tvar, gam, deno,inte.val){res<- beta.G(tvar,gam) - (1-deno)*unit.l.func(tvar,gam)*inte.val
return(res)}
```

Basically, I want to have 2 function b1.til and b2.til like this:

```
b1.til <- K0.operator.b(tvar,gam,deno=K0.deno[1],inte.val=K0.inte.val[2])
b2.til <- K0.operator.b(tvar,gam,deno=K0.deno[2],inte.val=K0.inte.val[2])
```

Then, again I need to integrate b1.til and b2.til with gam=lambda.es. How can I do without writing everything twice?
Thank you very much for looking. Any advice/help is much appreciated. I am grateful with any criticism for the code as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want function1 be based on K0.first.func and  have only two arguments (tvar and gam) but also to have deno be known to be deno[1] and val to be val[1] but not require that they be entered by subsequent users?

Comment: Yes, I want to get function1 and function2 like that. Then I need to apply the same operator onto them so I need to make them in the same list or vector.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this should succeed but you should actually provide real test cases for testing. At the moment we have no `unit.l.func` or values of deno or val available for testing or any test case where you know what the answer should be.

Try returning a function that is defined at a point where those two values are available. The function *should* then carry them forward as part of its environment. That's called a "closure":

```
function1 <- function(tvar, gam)
{ function(tvar, gam){ beta.G(tvar,gam) - 1/(1-deno[1])*(unit.l.func( tvar, gam)-1)*val[1]}
 }

function2 <- function(tvar, gam)
{ function(tvar, gam){ beta.G(tvar,gam) - 1/(1-deno[2])*(unit.l.func( tvar, gam)-1)*val[2]}
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much 42-. I may not understand you correctly, did you mean that I should define function1 and function2 separately and then I can combine them into 1 list? Because I will have a lot of subsequent operations applied onto these 2 functions, I don't want to write everything twice.

Comment: I was showing you how to return a function from a function. You only assigned a single function to a name. If you want to update your post to include a sample application with test data _and_ `unit.`.func` _and `beta.G`` _and_ test parameter vectors, I'll look at it again. At the moment your question seems insufficiently specific to support a coded response. See if you can operationalize the phrase: "a lot of subsequent operations applied onto these 2 functions".

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please let me know whether it is sufficiently specific enough? Thank you very much, 42-.